# Stacked bar graph showing only every other column

Tags: excel, graph

I am trying to create a 100% stacked bar graph in excel, however the resulting graph is only showing information for every other x-value. The x-axis is 134 values so I am not sure if the size is the problem or if it something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The X axis labels of a category axis (like in a a column or bar chart) is dynamically adjusted to the available space. When there are many columns/bars, not every column/bar will have a label. You can test that by making the chart wider/higher, to see how the X axis labels appear and disappar.

Having over 130 categorical items on an X axis is not good data visualisation. It's a rather horrible experience for the poor reader. Excel's behaviour is actually useful here. By not displaying all labels, it makes such a chart fairly unusable, and you may be inspired to think of better ways to visualise the data.

Maybe several smaller charts for segments of the data would be an option.

Comment: Thanks! It is for an initial data visualization so no need to worry about it being pretty yet.